# Connect Azure Data Factory to Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Linux Virtual Machine where it has got some zip files. I need to create an Azure Data Factory pipeline to get this data and place into Azure DataLake Gen 2.

Could anyone please suggest how can I connect to Azure VM using Data Factory?

Anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to copy from Azure vm using Azure data factory.
you can find supported data sources  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-copy-data-wizard-tutorial#next-steps)

what you can do is try to copy the data from vm to azure storage and from there you can copy to ADLs  Through ADF pipeline. You can use [az storage blob copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest)
 or [azcopy copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) to copy data from VM to azure storage.